# Error from Postfix server: mail for cacti.snowbarre.co.za loops back to myself

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam

My setup is that my central mail server, CM forward to an anti-spam server, cacti which acts as an SMTP server. On of the email addresses on CM has been getting 40 emails generated apparently as a bounce notification from Cacti, as shown below:

```
The mail system *<MAILER-DAEMON@cacti.snowbarre.co.za>: mail for cacti.snowbarre.co.za loops back to myself

Final-Recipient: rfc822; MAILER-DAEMON@cacti.snowbarre.co.za
Original-Recipient: rfc822;MAILER-DAEMON@cacti.snowbarre.co.za
Action: failed
Status: 5.4.6
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; mail for cacti.snowbarre.co.za loops back to myself*
```

He gets these emails even without sending anything. Incidentally he started receiving them on a day I had been spammed on the Cacti server. The spam source was located and dealt with but this client keeps getting these failure delivery emails.

I have checked the main.cf and the line `mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost` is there. This is affecting only one email address on a server with about 12000 mailboxes so it may not be a global issue.

```
root@cacti:~# postconf -n
2bounce_notice_recipient = abuse@snowbarre.co.za
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_notice_recipient = abuse@snowbarre.co.za
bounce_template_file = /etc/postfix/bounce.cf
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_level = 6
debug_peer_list = 172.17.243.13
delay_notice_recipient = abuse@snowbarre.co.za
error_notice_recipient = abuse@snowbarre.co.za
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 15000000
mydestination = smtp.snowbarreco.za, localhost.snowbarre.co.za, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.20.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/16
 172.17.0.0/16 196.x.x.0/24 196.x.x.0/24 196.x.x.0/26 192.168.0.0/16
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error either add system FQDN to mydestination or relay_domains. Postfix accepts mail for domain listed in virtual_mailbox_domains, virtual_alias_domains, and domains that resolve to IP addresses listed in inet_interfaces and proxy_interfaces. Update mydestination using postconf or by editing main.cf file:

```
  mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.example.com

  service postfix reload
```

Comment: From my out put there is the line mydestination = smtp.snowbarreco.za, localhost.snowbarre.co.za, localhost. What else do I have to change.

Comment: Add  cacti.snowball.co.za. Any domain must be in this list, that you want to get email to.

Comment: @Paddington `smtp.snowbarreco.za` is missing something ..........